# How to hide a single/particular order based on order id in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

How to hide an order in order page based on order id, not based on order status?

Comment: Hide one-row in order listing table is what you meant.?

Comment: Please consider explaining your goal and motivation more clearly, right now it seems that you are trying to hide a scam order.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant @mujuonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'admin_dashboard_subscriptions_filter_callback' );

function admin_dashboard_subscriptions_filter_callback() {
    global $pagenow, $post_type, $post;
    // Targeting subscriptions admin dashboard for specific user role
    $order_ids_to_hide = array( 244, 240 );

    if ( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && $post_type === 'shop_order' && in_array( $post->ID, $order_ids_to_hide ) ) :
    ?>
            <style>
            .post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> { display: none;}
            </style>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```